# CSS: make child width fit viewport when parent is wider?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, viewport

Is it possible in CSS alone to make a child element's width fit the viewport when its parent is wider than the viewport?

I am designing a user interface to fit within an existing, unresponsive, fixed-width site layout that I don't (yet) have any direct control over, and I'd like at least my interface to be responsive to fit mobile screens, even if the overall site layout does not. Pages incorporating my interface will at least be able to load an extra CSS file for the interface's styling, but leveraging this to alter the overall site layout on pages using my interface is a dicey proposition.

I'd rather not have to set a range of fixed-width breakpoints with @media queries if it's possible for CSS to scale my interface DIV width dynamically to fit any viewport size. For illustration, see this mockup:

[Layout Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtIqF.png)

...where I control the Content DIV and want its width to fit any viewport as shown, but I have no control over the fixed-width Container, Header and Footer DIVs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!

Use vw and vh units. 100vw is equal to the viewport width, while 100vh is the viewport height.

http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Also make sure, when dealing with mobile to include

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" />`

so it won't zoom all the way out by default.

Comment: Excellent! That's exactly what I needed, much thx. Apparently vw/vh units aren't supported at all in the default Android browser (of all things!), so I'll still have to declare a fixed-width fallback before the vw width, but I'll take it.